# Generate ranges from entries in a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, command

I have a txt file containing entries as below

```
1
2
3
4
7
8
9
12
14
15
```

I need to generate ranges as below

```
1-4
7-9
12-12
14-15
```

How do I achieve the above output?

This is what I tried:

```
awk '{q=$1}{f=$1}{print $q} $1!=p+1{print l"-"f}{l=p+1}{p=$1} END{print}' filename
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide some code with what have you tried. Thank you

Comment: awk '{q=$1}{f=$1}{print $q} $1!=p+1{print l"-"f}{l=p+1}{p=$1} END{print}' filename  Filename is the txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say...

```
awk -v OFS=- 'prev+1<$0 {print first ? first : 1,prev; first=$0}
              {prev=$0}
              END {print first, prev}' file
```

For your given file it returns:

```
$ awk -v OFS=- 'prev+1<$0 {print first ? first : 1,prev; first=$0} {prev=$0} END {print first, prev}' file
1-4
7-9
12-12
14-15
```

I won't go through your attempt `awk '{q=$1}{f=$1}{print $q} $1!=p+1{print l"-"f}{l=p+1}{p=$1} END{print}' filename` but I do suggest you to use more representative variable names, as well as to start from a little piece and then make your script grow. Otherwise, it becomes a jungle you want to throw away once it does not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot fedorqui. You saved my day!